# Still shot from video on iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, photos, camera, screen-capture

I took a video with my iPhone 5s. I would like to print one frame of this video as a still picture. I tried taking a screen shot of it, but ended up with the menu on the top and bottom of the picture. Is there an easier way of keeping one frame of a video as a still picture?

Answer (score 1):

If you tap the screen, the top and bottom bars disappear, and you can take your screen shot then. However, taking a screenshot may give you a lower quality result that may not look nice printed out. iMovie (Mac or for iPhone) should be able to do this without a loss in quality, as well as other video editors / certain video players (e.g. VLC).

Comment: Or with VLC's snapshot feature.

Comment: In iOS10 you're stuck with the pause icon in the middle of the image.

Comment: @JustinEmlay pause icon? What app?

Comment: Stock photo app to view videos.  When you pause it the start icon is right in the middle.  http://i.imgur.com/roeoXlT.jpg

Comment: Play it then pause it and it doesn't come back, at least not in iOS 10.3.3

Answer (score 0):

There are several apps if you want to do it on iphone. 
I used Vhoto for a while ago. They also added gif conversion. Its free so you can try easily
Here are the key features taken from itunes description.

> Key Features:
>
> - Record or import your videos
> - Vhoto finds and creates GIFs and pics
> - Trim to create the perfect loop
> - Nudge to get the best moment
> - Easily text GIFs and post anywhere to Tumblr, Instagram, Facebook, Twitter
> - 100% free!